# How to create an Single Class coexist with Generic in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, singleton

I have a Single Class like this:

```
class Single {
    static let sharedInstance: Single = Single()
    ...
}
```

But I want use Generic in this Class like this:

```
class Single<T: Hashable> {
    static let sharedInstance: Single = Single()
    var dic: [T: Any] = [:] // Here use the Generic
}
```

I got this result from Xcode

> Static stored properties not supported in generic types

I have search this error in stackoverflow, but all the answer for this is not suit for me. Like this one([How to define static constant in a generic class in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543628/how-to-define-static-constant-in-a-generic-class-in-swift))

How can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe make `sharedInstance` a static computed property?

Comment: Yes, you are right! But why make a static computed property can fix this question?It's also a static single instance..

Comment: I'm confused about how this would be used. Do you intend to have several singletons, one for each hashable type? If so, how would you instantiate them - the `static` doesn't "do" that, as it doesn't refer to  `T`? Or do you simply want the one singleton to be able to store any hashable key in your dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a generic type using a static computed property as follows:

```
class Single<T: Hashable> {
  static var sharedInstance: Single? {
    if self.sharedInstance != nil {
        return self.sharedInstance
    } else {
        return Single()
    }
  }
  var dic: [T: Any] = [:]
}
```

Comment: This creates a new Single instance every time the var is accessed. So it's not suitable for a singleton use case.

Comment: @PranavKasetti Thanks, this really helped but I don't why it gives me a warning "All paths through this function will call itself" any idea?

Answer (score -1):

I take it you simply want the one singleton to be able to store any hashable key in your dictionary? If so, do the following:

```
class Single {
    static let sharedInstance: Single = Single()
    var dic: [AnyHashable : Any] = [:]
}

Single.sharedInstance.dic["Grimxn"] = 1
Single.sharedInstance.dic[1] = "Grimxn"

Single.sharedInstance.dic // [1: "Grimxn", "Grimxn": 1] as required
```

Comment: Here is my Scenes: I use the Single as a Tool Class, and I want to have a dictionary to store some instances, the keys are a kind of enum. I want to send an uncertain enum key to get an instance, so I use Generic to match the uncertain enum. The Hashable is that dictionary's key must Hashable.

Comment: sorry, I try your suggestion, It works too, but I think Pranav Kasetti's suggestion suit me better. Thank you any more!